# Ошибка Permission denied

Tags: python

Выходит ошибка

> ```
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
> ```

при попытке выполнения этого кода:

```
with open("D:\Ali's codes\Telegram bots\Wikigraphia photos", "rb") as f:
    usa_photo = f.read()
```

Comment: операционная система виндоуз, я полагаю?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете открыть директорию на чтение, нужно открыть файл.
Использовать пробелы в именах файлов и  директорий плохая идея.

Comment: "Использовать пробелы в именах файлов и директорий плохая идея." - вполне нормальная идея. Ну и к вопросу это не относится. Но первая часть правильная.